# Django Inheritance gives import errors

Tags: python, django, inheritance

I have one class (`DeckDeviceUtil`) with an abstract function (`get_active_deckdevices`) who needs to be inherited by 2 classes (Deck and Device). The structure is as follows:

A.py

```
from models import Deck
    class DeckDeviceUtil:
        @property
        @abstractmethod
        def deckdevice(self):
            pass

        def get_active_deckdevices(self):
            #somecode

    class Device(models.Model, DeckDeviceUtil):
        #somecode

    class DeckDevice(models.Model):
        #uses Deck
```

B.py

```
from backend.devices.models import DeckDeviceUtil

class Deck(models.Model, DeckDeviceUtil):
    #somecode
```

I get following error:

```
from backend.house.models import Deck
ImportError: cannot import name 'Deck'
```

probably because the 2 python files/classes need each other.
When I try to do the imports inside the classes there are other errors

when import DeckDeviceUtil inside Deck :

```
class Deck(models.Model, DeckDeviceUtil):
NameError: name 'DeckDeviceUtil' is not defined
```

when import Deck inside Device:

```
from backend.house.models import Deck
ImportError: cannot import name 'Deck'
```

Important: Device needs to import Deck

What's the best way to solve this?

Comment: You are making a cyclic import. You thus should break the cycle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Circular (or cyclic) imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how can I break it?

Comment: Why do you import `Deck` in the file where you define `DeckDeviceUtil` and `Device`?

Comment: @IainShelvington the DeckDevice classe uses this. I added to the code. Sorry for that

Comment: Can you show where it's used? If it's used in a foreign key you can reference it using a string to prevent circular imports

Comment: Yes indeed as a foreign key

Comment: @IainShelvington if I put it in brackets I get "ValueError: Related model 'Deck' cannot be resolved"